# Errors on Data migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Add-Migration InitialCreate

While running this command , an error is coming while creating an API in ASP .NET

Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- Add-Migration InitialCreate
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I do not have Migration folder as well as migration table in my database.

Comment: Did you install _Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools_ from NuGet?

Answer (score 0):

1. **View** -> **Other windows** -> **Package Manager Console** then run
2. **install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**
   Now run your command **Add-Migration** and your good to go.